# MonoTouch Designer Class Not Available In XCode

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to build a custom TableViewCell, and so far I have created a xib file and laid it out in XCode designer.  However, I cannot find my class in the drop down in identity inspector, and I cannot locate the generated class when in content assister.

Is there something beyond creating the xib in MonoDev to make my designer class available to XCode designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Xamarin support:

> When creating a custom UITableViewCell (and wanting to use the
>   designer), you have to use a bit of a "hacky" process to get the
>   code-behind file to work. You are going to want to add the class as a
>   iPhone (or iPad or Universal) UIViewController, change the superclass
>   of the class you just created to UITableViewCell. Make your changes in
>   the Xcode designer (delete view and add UITableViewCell), and then
>   make your changes in your code-behind file.
>
> There is a great tutorial on how to do this here:
>   http://www.arcticmill.com/2012/05/uitableview-with-custom-uitableviewcell.html

Answer (score 1):

The (C#) class needs to have a Register attribute:

```cs
[Register ("MyClass")]
public class MyClass : UITableViewCell
{
}
```

Comment: In newer versions of MonoTouch, you can also type your class name in XCode, save and alt+tab to MonoDevelop, and MonoDevelop will generate a new class for you with everything hooked up.